# Convergence of integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

How can we solve the following integral?
$$\int_0^M \exp{\left(\frac{-0.5}{1+x^2}\right)}dx$$ , where M is very large.
Does this integral converge to some constant?

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The integral does not converge, because for $x \to +\infty$
$$\exp\left(\frac{-0.5}{1+x^2}\right) > \frac1x$$
and
$$\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac1x\mathrm dx$$
with $\epsilon > 0$ diverges.

Comment: what, if limit is bounded at a large value of M..?

Comment: @Pravin: I'm not sure I understood correctly. Do you refer to the fact that $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-0.5}{1 + x^2}\right) = 1\ ?$$

Comment: yea, it may be...but I am asking if x tends to M (very large).?

Comment: @Pravin: If $x \to M$ and $M \in \mathbb R$ the limit is simply $$\exp\left(\frac{-0.5}{1 + M^2}\right)$$ because $e^x$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.